# Save components in list or array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor

I have a index.razor, that has a for loop that generates let's say 100 components (those display text, and a couple more vlaues), now i want to hava a reference of every component, is there a way to save those in a List or an array?

I tryed it myself in many ways but I get the name of the component displayed in the html.

addPdfComp is executed by a button:

```
public void addPdfComp(int type)
{
    var newComponent = new PdfComp();
    newComponent.text = "some test text";
    PdfComponentsList.Add(newComponent);
}
```

and to display the components:

```
@foreach (var comp in PdfComponentsList)
{
        <div>@comp</div>
}
```

result:
[see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVzq.png)

Edit:
The component itself:

```
<div class="row p-1 " style="border:solid; ">
<h5>TextComponent</h5>
<div>
    <label>X</label>
    <input type="number" class="col-2" @bind-value="_x"/>
    <label>Y</label>
    <input type="number" class="col-2" @bind-value="_y"/>
    <label>Text</label>
    <input type="text" class="col-4" @bind-value="text" />
</div>
```

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public string text { get; set;  } = "Missing text";
[Parameter]
public string type { get; set; } = "noone";
[Parameter]
public int _x { get; set; } = 0;
[Parameter]
public int _y { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Comment: My intention is not to use `.ToString()`, but to display the component itself as if i just typed:  `<PdfComp></PdfComp>` 100 times. (see update).

Comment: Edited the snippet, (it was properly set in VS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default string representation for an object is the fully qualified class name for that object, which is what you're seeing. This means that whatever `PdfComp` is, it doesn't have a meaningful `.ToString()` implementation.

And that's all Razor syntax really does in this case, it just emits output as a string.  So `@something` will basically evaluate `something` as a string and write it to the output.

Based on a comment above:

> My intention is [...] to display the component itself as if i just typed: `<PdfComp></PdfComp>` 100 times.

An instance of `PdfComp` in C# code is not the same thing as an instance of `<PdfComp></PdfComp>` in the markup.  (Though I imagine they are *very closely analogous* somewhere in the depths of the framework.)  What you want isn't a list of object instances, but a list of the data your view needs to render the markup.

So, structurally, more like this:

```
// PdfComponentsList here is a list of strings
PdfComponentsList.Add("some test text");
```

And then loop through it in the markup to display the elements:

```
@foreach (var pdf in PdfComponentsList)
{
    <PdfComp text="@pdf"></PdfComp>
}
```

You could also make `PdfComponentsList` a list of some object to hold multiple properties, for example:

```
PdfComponentsList.Add(new SomeObject { Text = "some test text" });
```

And in the markup:

```
@foreach (var pdf in PdfComponentsList)
{
    <PdfComp text="@pdf.Text"></PdfComp>
}
```

Comment: That was my original idea, but using 2 components (first to be in the html and the other to have the data) is something i really want to avoid, i ended up using a simple version (looks weird and might be bad practice) of your answer:
`@foreach (var pdf in PdfComponentsList)
{
    <PdfComp text="@pdf.Text"></PdfComp>
}`
but the component pdf is the same as PdfComp, translated would be somthing like:
`<PdfComp text="PdfComp .text"></PdfComp>`

Basically, the component uses its own values into an instance of itself...